# program running in Tizen gear s2 can't get same result in with windows?

Tags: tizen, samsung-gear-s2

I am developing a project in tizen gear S2, but I try to use the same code in my pc but I can't get the same result with in gear s2, so what's wrong with this problem?

Comment: Which project you're trying to run in your Gear device? And what do you mean by this line "I try to use the same code in my pc" ? Did you mean emulator by the word pc?

Answer (score 0):

Gear S2 is commercial device and use own theme. But PC emulator is raw Tizen platform and use reference theme. So, It you use default theme and UI framework(EFL), Your widget may show different theme and style.